# CNN to learn and visualize 2d features

Tags: deep-learning, classification, mnist

In the paper [Large-Margin Softmax Loss for Convolutional Neural Networks](https://arxiv.org/abs/1612.02295) the author has a figure as below:
[image]

He is claiming that he is using only 2d features to classify MNIST with a CNN. How is he doing that? Is he reducing the dimension of MNIST images to 2 and how? How do you visualize such figures in 2D if the classification is for 10 classes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I got my answer from the following post:
http://unixnme.blogspot.com/2018/04/dimensionality-reduction-and-scattered.html